# using google fluentd to log from compute engine instance in google cloud

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fluentd, google-stackdriver

I got a problem with the logging agent from *Google Cloud*.

What i wanted was to use the [*google-fluentd*](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) (based on fluentd) on a webserver to collect the logs and sent it to *Stackdriver Logging Api*.

The server itself is a *Google Compute Instance*, so the Agent doesn't needs credentials for the Logging Api, as Google mentioned in their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/). It also provides an external IP-Adress which is necessary for Stackdriver Logging. Scopes for this instance are ok, Stackdriver Logging Api with write permissions.

The installation was successful, thanks to the documentation of google.
No errors, the software sends a testlog to the *Stackdriver Logging Api*, but when I look into stackdriver logging and there are no logs for *GCE VM Instances*

I looked into the log..

```
tail -f /var/log/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.log
```

Again, no errors.

I checked the status of the deamon with

```
sudo systemctl status google-fluentd
```

output was *active (running)*

I restarted the daemon, after that i restarted the instance.
Log seems to be ok and daemon is still running fine, but still no logs.

I sent a  log with
    logger "test"
the test log was not shown in Stackdriver Api nor in the logs.

What i did next was to install the agent on another System. It worked perfectly. Just the Web-Server had problems with this phenomenon.

Does anybody had that problem before too and knows a solution for this?

*This was my second post, so if you need more informations or something i will add them*

Comment: Can you provide us with more information about your Web-Server VM to replicate this behavior? what OS and web server is it running on VM? Is any internal firewall configured?

Comment: If you solve this issue, you might consider posting an answer so the community can benefit from your experience.